# Tool to determine which normal form(s) a database's table violates

Tags: database

I am looking for a program that can determine in which [normal form(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) a table is (e.g. [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)).

If possible, I should be able to give an entire database schema as input, and not just one table of it. I would prefer a free, graphical program running on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

(Yes I am aware that [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) is often useful, no intent to start a debate on the usefulness of database normalization!)

Comment: Relational database? What schema format? (SQL?)

Comment: Does your database use identical field names for related fields across tables? Otherwise all bets are off ;-)

Comment: Foreign key constraints take care of related fields are assigned .